# Change plist root type to Array in Xcode 4?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, xcode4

In Xcode, I had gotten quite used to creating `plists` to store simple arrays of static data.

However, in Xcode 4 I can't figure out how to change the default root type of a `plist` from `Dictionary` to `Array`.

Just one of many frustrations I've been having with Xcode 4. Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: I figured out at least a temporary fix: create the .plist file, then open it in TextEdit and change the XML tags to from <dict> to <array>. Still, there must be a way in Xcode 4. Why doesn't "Show raw keys/values" seem to do anything?

Comment: I don't have an answer, but a slightly quicker workaround is to choose the 'Version' editor view (⌥⇧⌘), which allows you to edit raw XML. Which it would have to do, I guess. I assume 'Show raw keys/values' hasn't been implemented yet (like much of XCode 4 it seems).

Comment: Same problem here. Very confused why XCode 4 plist editor is not showing root element. But there is a strange option "Property List Type". It's values say nothing about type of root element, but may be this option affects type of root element...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just right-click the .plist file and open file as source code. Now we will be able to see the xml file.

Replace the `<dict/>` to `<array/>`. Now build the project once. Things will be all right.

Answer (score 1):

My technique: create a new row, set its type to array, put the items you want in the root array in it.  Cut the array, then you have an empty plist.  Then paste, and you have an array with root type of Array, with the items from the array you created.